# Using rle to eliminate first and last sequences

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, run-length-encoding

I am trying to solve a problem with R using `rle()` (or another relevant function) but am not sure where to start.  The problem is as follows - `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` and `qux` can be in one of three positions - `A`, `B`, or `C`.

Their first position will always be `A`, and their last position will always be `C`, but their positions in between are random.

My objective is to eliminate the first A *or* first sequence of A's, and the last C *or* the last sequence of C's.  For example:

```
> foo
   position
1         A
2         A
3         A
4         B
5         B
6         A
7         B
8         A
9         C
10        C

> output(foo)
   position

4         B
5         B
6         A
7         B
8         A


> bar
   position
1         A
2         B
3         A
4         B
5         A
6         C
7         C
8         C
9         C
10        C

> output(bar)
   position

2         B
3         A
4         B
5         A

> baz
   position
1         A
2         A
3         A
4         A
5         A
6         C
7         C
8         C
9         C
10        C

> output(baz)
NULL

> qux
  position
1        A
2        C
3        A
4        C
5        A
6        C

> output(qux)
  position
2        C
3        A
4        C
5        A
```

Basic `rle()` will tell me about the sequences and their lengths but it will not preserve row indices.  How should one go about solving this problem?

```
> rle(foo$position)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:6] 3 2 1 1 1 2
  values : chr [1:6] "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "C"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `rle`.  The idea would be to subset the 1st and last `values`, check whether it is equal to 'A', 'C', assign it to `NA` and convert that to a logical `vector` for subsetting

```
i1 <- !is.na(inverse.rle(within.list(rle(foo$position), 
     values[c(1, length(values))][values[c(1, length(values))] == c("A", "C")] <- NA)))
foo[i1, , drop = FALSE]
#    position
#4        B
#5        B
#6        A
#7        B
#8        A
```

Answer (score 3):

I would write a function using `cumsum` where we check how many of first consecutive values start with `first_position` and how many of last consecutive values start with `last_position` and remove them.

```
get_reduced_data <- function(dat, first_position, last_position) {
    dat[cumsum(dat != first_position) != 0 &
   rev(cumsum(rev(dat) != last_position) != 0)]
 }

get_reduced_data(foo, first_position, last_position)
#[1] "B" "B" "A" "B" "A"

get_reduced_data(bar, first_position, last_position)
#[1] "B" "A" "B" "A"

get_reduced_data(baz, first_position, last_position)
#character(0)

get_reduced_data(qux, first_position, last_position)
#[1] "C" "A" "C" "A"
```

**data**

```
foo <- c("A", "A","A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C")
bar <- c("A", "B","A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C")
baz <- c(rep("A", 5), rep("C", 5))
qux <- c("A", "C", "A", "C", "A", "C")
first_position <- "A"
last_position <- "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution without `rle` by creating an index and subsetting rows to between first occurrence of non-A and last occurrence of non-C:

```
library(data.table)
output <- function(DT) {
    DT[, rn:=.I][,{
            mn <- min(which(position!="A"))
            mx <- max(which(position!="C"))
            if (mn > mx) return(NULL)
            .SD[mn:mx]
        }]
}

output(setDT(foo))
#   position rn
#1:        B  4
#2:        B  5
#3:        A  6
#4:        B  7
#5:        A  8

output(setDT(baz))
#NULL
```

data:

```
foo <- fread("position
A
A
A
B
B
A
B
A
C
C")

baz <- fread("position
A
A
A
A
A
C
C
C
C
C")
```

Comment: Take care of coner case. This doesn't work for `baz`.

Comment: thanks, @mt1022. I didnt notice the scroll bar on the right and was scratching my head abt `baz` and `qux`

Answer (score 0):

A [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach could be,

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, grp := rleid(position)][
  !(grp == 1 & position == 'A' | grp == max(grp) & position == 'C'), ][
    , grp := NULL][]
```

which gives,

> ```
>    position
> 1:        B
> 2:        B
> 3:        A
> 4:        B
> 5:        A
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be two-fold. Triming 'first' and 'last' elements, and identifying what constitutes 'first' and 'last'. I like your `rle()` approach, because it maps many possibilities into a common structure. So the task is to write a function to mask the first and last elements of a vector of any length

```
mask_end = function(x) {
    n = length(x)
    mask = !logical(n)
    mask[c(min(1, n), max(0, n))] = FALSE  # allow for 0-length x
    mask
}
```

This is very easy to test comprehensively

```
> mask_end(integer(0))
logical(0)
> mask_end(integer(1))
[1] FALSE
> mask_end(integer(2))
[1] FALSE FALSE
> mask_end(integer(3))
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> mask_end(integer(4))
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

The solution (returning the mask; easy to modify to return the actual values, `x[inverse.rle(r)]`) is then

```
mask_end_runs = function(x) {
    r = rle(x)
    r$values = mask_end(r$values)
    inverse.rle(r)
}
```